# double save image when i take a picture

Tags: android

my device is samsung s first image is saved in sdcard/DCIM  second image is saved in sdcard/mydirectory 
why???

and what should i do? i dont want first image

here is my code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);    
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(getTempFile()));    
startActivityForResult(intent,TAKE_PHOTO_CODE);
```

..

```
private File getTempFile(){
  File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"universalmemo/"+"data/"+"memo/"+"picturememo");
  if(!root.exists()){
    root.mkdirs();
  }
  File file = new File(root,getDateTime());
  return file;
}
```

..

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {     
    Intent intent2 = new Intent();
    if(requestCode == TAKE_PHOTO_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){

        intent2.putExtra("Filename", datetime);
        setResult(RESULT_OK,intent2);
    }
    else setResult(RESULT_CANCELED,intent2);
    finish();           
}
```

..

thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a galaxy s problem , you have to deleted image that create in folder that you don't want by deleted last file